# Grab all value between 2 XML tags

Tags: xml, powershell, scripting

In PowerShell I'm trying to retrieve all the string values between 2 XML tags based on the category attribute.

Example code shows:

```
<Report name="test" category="thisone">
  <String>test</String>
  <String>test2</String>
  <Report name="new test" category="hi">
    <String>hello</String>
    <String>hi again</String>
  </Report>
</Report>
```

So I'd like to output those 4 strings, based on the `<Report>` tag with the category "thisone". I'm having trouble since both XML tags begin with "Report" but the category "hi" is a child of "thisone", so its strings I also need.

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe your XML to `Select-Xml` and do an XPath search against it like this:

```
$text = Get-Content C:\Path\To\File.xml
$text | Select-Xml -XPath '//Report[@category="thisone"]//String'|%{$_.Node.'#text'}
```

The important part is the XPath search. `//` means everything from the root of the XML, then you look for `Report` nodes that have an attribute of `category` with a value of `"thisone"`. Then it look at all of the nodes past that (again denoted by `//`) for `String` nodes. It passes all of those `string` nodes to a `ForEach-Object` loop (alias `%` used), and for each of those it expands the Node property, and the #text property within that. This results in:

```
test
test2
hello
hi again
```

To output those string to a file you could pipe the second line to `Set-Content` (or `Out-File`, but that cmdlet is a little outdated IMO).

```
$text | Select-Xml -XPath '//Report[@category="thisone"]//String'|%{$_.Node.'#text'} | Set-Content C:\Path\To\NewFile.txt
```

Or to output to both screen and file you can use `Tee-Object` such as:

```
$text | Select-Xml -XPath '//Report[@category="thisone"]//String'|%{$_.Node.'#text'} | Tee-Object -FilePath C:\Path\To\NewFile.txt
```

Comment: It looks like that worked! I used Out-File and that worked too. What I failed to realize is that it's combining the String values for ALL of them (all the categories with 'thisone'). Is there a way I can store them as a variable in array to distinguish one from another? That would allow me to Out-File each occurrence...

Comment: Well, sure, if you redirect the output to a file then it wouldn't display anything. That is kind of the purpose there. If you want to output to a file as well as display things you can use `Tee-Object`

Comment: I edited my comment as I had a typo before. I have it outputting to a file now, but I'm having trouble separating the first occurrence of "thisone" with the second one, as it's dumping everything in one. I'm thinking storing them as variables in array would be the way to go...

Comment: I just noticed it's not returning my <String>  </String>. I have some empty <String> to separate them in the output... I believe it has to do with this part: |%{$_.Node.'#text'}   Can I modify that to include the text and those empty ones? Thx

Comment: No, that just expands the property that actually contains the text string. Are your empty strings nested under the 'thisone' category? Can you update the question with a more accurate example to test against?